# two database connections with mysql in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to connect to two databases as one database is used for login and other db is used to fetch data for logged in user.

I have created two DB connections as following, but it is overwriting the previous connection

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 

//second connection
var myConnection = require('express-myconnection');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

app.use(
connection(mysql,{
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user1',
    password : 'pass1',
    port : 3306, //port mysql
    database:'database1'
},'pool') //or single
);

app.use(
myConnection(mysql,{
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user2',
    password : 'pass2',
    port : 3306, //port mysql
    database:'database2'
},'pool') //or single
);
```

Comment: The reason the first connection is being over written is because you are setting the same middleware on the same router (app). If you show a sample of your routes as well we should be able to provide a solution using different routers for each.

Comment: As you can see in the source code, no matter what you name your function, the connection is always bound to req.getConnection - with no option to change it. https://github.com/pwalczyszyn/express-myconnection/blob/master/lib/express-myconnection.js#L82

Comment: I know it is not in the scope of this question, but I was wondering why you are keeping this info separated into two different db's

Answer (score 2):

Ok!
For connecting second database I have used mysql connector file containing the pool and assigned it to a variable "newConnection"  :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 

var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

app.use(
connection(mysql,{
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user1',
    password : 'pass1',
    port : 3306, //port mysql
    database:'database1'
},'pool') //or single
);
    var newConnection = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user2',
    password : 'pass2',
    port : 3306, 
    database:'database2'});
    app.set('connection_user',newConnection);//setting DB configuration in a variable
```

Later you can simply include the connector in another file lets call it webservice.js:

```
var connection_user = request.app.get('connection_user');
connection_user.getConnection(function(){});
```

now using "connection_user" variable we are connected to 2nd database.
hope you got it!